# Activity feed (like FB timeline): What is the logic to obtain the latest actions in the database?

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my application, there are 10-20 various kinds of actions that I want to display in activity feed:

- users sign up, become friends with each other and follow each other
- users register objects, buy and sell objects, follow objects
- users register sets of objects and add objects to the sets of objects.

Everything is being stored in a mysql database.

How do I obtain the latest actions/events and display them in an activity feed?

In my android app I have a ListView for the activity feed and an ENUM object describing those different kinds of actions, so the list view can be fed different sets of events and display different layouts for each event, but I dont know how to get the latest actions in the database in order to feed the activity.

What I was thinking of doing is to insert an ENUM EVENT in an EVENTS table in mysql each time a subject gets added, each time a user registers, or a user does something and then get the latest 10 events from that table and send it to the app, but how do I link certain event from that table to something happening in the database?

I have never learned how to create an activity and Im improvising but I dont know whether Im on the right path and if I am, how to implement that logic.

PS: I have an extremely basic undestanding of MySQL, so be gentle :)

Comment: update your question with your database schema. It will be very useful.

Comment: You need to timestamp your events

Comment: the whole database or just the events table?

Comment: I am timestampingall events, even the ones I dont need a timestamp for (cuz I dont know whether I may not need it in the future)

Comment: Basically you can have a field in your table that store the current time the entry got created/updated such as UpdateTime. Whenever you are creating or updating an entry, update the UpdateTime field with current time. Then while fetching result do a ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC with limit.

Comment: but what should I fetch for?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a user table, and that you have an event table and a table that links the user to the event so try

```
SELECT (*|[columns you want]) 
FROM events E
INNER JOIN events_users EU
  ON EU.event_id = E.id
INNER JOIN users U
  ON EU.event_id = U.id
ORDER BY EU.(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 30
```

And without aliasing

```
SELECT (*|[columns you want]) 
FROM events
INNER JOIN events_users
  ON events_users.event_id = events.id
INNER JOIN users
  ON events_users.event_id = users.id
ORDER BY events_users.(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 30
```

Bare minimum

```
user (id)
events_users (user_id, event_id, timestamp)
event(id)
```

Comment: But how do I link those entries from events to the users and objects that were involved with the events, so I know what data to display

Comment: the return of that query will be that some user has followed another user, but how do I know which user followed who?

Comment: :((( I dont know what E  means, I dontknow what EU means and I dont know what U means in that example. and I dont know what ON command does. Can you tell me what should I study in order to understand that?

Comment: Yeah sure, try googling sql alias. It's just a shortcut so when you want to reference a column on the table later you can do it with the alias eg EU.event_id is events_users.event_id just shorter

Comment: can you please change it to a version without the aliasing so I get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

In your event table define a type field which corresponds to each activity types such as

```
type 1: user registration
type 2: add comment
```

etc..
Then you can have a field in your table that store the current time the entry got created/updated such as UpdateTime. Whenever you are creating or updating an entry, update the UpdateTime field with current time. Then while fetching result do a ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC with limit.

```
SELECT id, userid, name, type, activity ,updateTime
FROM users usr INNER JOIN events ev
ON ev.user = usr.userid
WHERE updateTime > 0
ORDER BY updateTime LIMIT 0,10;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a64ec/2)

A good tutorial for MySQL beginner is [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)